# Why resource provides has two labels - terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am currently learning terraform, still i can't understand, why resource provider block needs two labels as below ? What are the use cases for two labels ?

resource "**aws_instance**" "**example**"

Regards,
Chin

Comment: I don't think the downvotes on this question are fair. Even in the [Terraform language documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/index.html#about-the-terraform-language) it says blocks are in the form `<BLOCK TYPE> "<BLOCK LABEL>" "<BLOCK LABEL>"`. This can be confusing to beginners.

Answer (score 3):

You are telling Terraform that you are declaring a resource **of type** `aws_instance` **with name** `example`. Only one of those things is a label, the other is the type of resource you want Terraform to create and manage for you.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are familiar with OOP concepts. So, I am gonna use java to explain.

Lets say you have a java class box defined.

```
class box {
      double length;
      double width;
      double height;
}
```

Now you usually need to create an object to use that class or to refer that class. You can have multiple object of the same class. right ?

```
new myBox1 = box(length=11,width=7,height=5)
new myBox2 = box(length=9,width=4,height=8)
```

Now lets try to understand the terraform.
There are three components in resource "aws_instance" "example"

1. **resource :** It tells the terraform core engine that you want to use a terraform resource. In your case its an aws_instance. It could have also been any other resource like aws_s3 or aws_rds_cluster etc. Imagine it's your keyword class.
2. **aws_instance :** It's your selected resource you wanna use. Imagine it's your class box.
3. **example :** It's the identifier you are gonna use to store your terraform state. The instances may have separate values. One can be t2.micro and another can be something else. Imagine it as your object myBox1 or myBox2.

Terraform stores the current state of your infrastructure in a state file be it local or remote. And, in practice you will have multiple aws instances. How can you or terraform differentiate between them. It identifies each of your aws_instace by the name you provide. For instance,

```
resource "aws_instance" "example1"
resource "aws_instance" "example2"
```

aws_instance.example1 and aws_instance.example2 are two different object or two different instances. For the same reason you can not have the same identifier. (If your terraform state is same).

In short, think of that as class and object. :)